# How to save data from Unity to excel

Tags: c#, excel, database, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;
using OfficeOpenXml;

public class test22222 : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject inputName;
    public GameObject emailAddress;
    public GameObject password;

    private string Name;
    private string EmailAddress;
    private string Password;

    public List <User> users= new List<User>();
 
    public string excelFileName, sheetName;

    
public void Submit()
    {
        string excelFilePath = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + excelFileName + ".xlsx";
        if (!Directory.Exists(Application.streamingAssetsPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.streamingAssetsPath);
        }
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(excelFileName);
        if (!fileInfo.Exists)
        {
            fileInfo = new FileInfo(excelFilePath);
        }

        
            using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
        {
            ExcelWorksheet excelWorksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetName);
           
            excelWorksheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "Name";
            excelWorksheet.Cells["B1"].Value = "EmailAddress";
            excelWorksheet.Cells["C1"].Value = "Password";

            for (int i = 0; i < users.Count; i++)
            {
                excelWorksheet.Cells[i + 2, 1].Value = users[i].inputName.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
                excelWorksheet.Cells[i + 2, 2].Value = users[i].emailAddress.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
                excelWorksheet.Cells[i + 2, 3].Value = users[i].password.GetComponent<InputField>().text;

            }
            
                    package.Save();
               
            }
     
        }

}

public class User
{
    public GameObject inputName;
    public GameObject emailAddress;
    public GameObject password;

    private string Name;
    private string EmailAddress;
    private string Password;
}
```

I try to colloceted all the user information from unity into an excel file. and now it can only create an excel file only with the title, no input inforamations.the tutorial i was followed he writes data in the inspector, i tried that as well and it works. so i transfar it into the an UI page but it failed.

[image: login page]

[image: Excel]

Comment: Can you use CSV?  CSV is vastly easier to work with in code, and Excel can open it just fine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thanks for your comment. However it doesn't work as well. It seems that the coding I wrote cannot collect the input fields.

Comment: Hi Shiyuan, in your code, i don't see any place where List <User> users list is populated with any data. You have allocated memory for it only. By the time you call the Submit logic, check how many items are there in the users list. If it is 0, hardcode some values as users and try again. If it works you only have to trouble shoot why users object is not filled by the time u call the method

Comment: Either way for sure you would not want to somewhere store user passwords as plain text without any encryption ^^ Is this a `WebGL` build? In that case rather host your thing on a proper backend server that also provides a proper database + user and authentication management ... Asp.NET Core + EntityFramework  for instance which a) allows you to stick with `c#` and b) comes with a full functional user management by default (e.g. creating the solution with Rider, Visual Studio, etc)